# putextra and getextra not passing string to next activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have three activities A,B and C

In my B activity I have one imageview, when I get a String from activity A to B, the imageview should be visible.

When I get a String from activity C to B then the imageview should not be visible.

```
//From activity A
Intent iin= getIntent();
Bundle b = iin.getExtras();
//From Activity C
Intent i2=getIntent();
Bundle abcd=i2.getExtras();

if(b!=null)
{
    String j =(String) b.get("arrowvisi");

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), j, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(j==b.get("arrowvisi"))
    {
        img_back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Operational arrow visible", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    else
    {
        if(abcd!=null)
        {
            String jst =(String) abcd.get("arrow_val");
            if(jst==abcd.get("arrow_val"))
            {
                img_back.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "scan dispatch visble", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                //img_back.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                System.out.println("from scan dispatch");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "scan dispatch not visible", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Operational not visible", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: why you are write two getIntent() here.. and where you are setting put extra to activity

Comment: cuz i m getting intent from two different activity..read queation carefully first

Comment: How to pass data from `C` to `B` Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
String j = (String) b.get("arrowvisi");
```

with

```
String j = b.getString("arrowvisi");
```

and

```
String jst = (String) abcd.get("arrow_val");
```

with

```
String jst = abcd.getString("arrow_val");
```

also string comparison should be like

```
j.equals(b.getString("arrowvisi")) // change again
```

and

```
jst.equals(abcd.getString("arrow_val"))  // change again
```

So, the final ans should be something like

```
//From activity A
Intent iin = getIntent();
Bundle b = iin.getExtras();

//From Activity C
Intent i2 = getIntent();
Bundle abcd = i2.getExtras();

if(b != null){
    String j = "String to check"; // Replace content inside "" with your string 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), j, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(j.equals(b.getString("arrowvisi"))){
        img_back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Operational arrow visible", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        if(abcd != null){
            String jst = "String to check"; // Replace with string you want to check
            if(jst.equals(abcd.getString("arrow_val"))){
                img_back.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "scan dispatch visble", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    //img_back.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    System.out.println("from scan dispatch");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "scan dispatch not visible", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Operational not visible", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Also **note** that, doing something like

```
String jst = abcd.getString("arrow_val"));
if(jst.equals(abcd.getString("arrow_val"))) // this will be always true
```

this, will result in `if` statement being always true.

**2 options :**

1) Remove if statement because always true.

2) change String `jst = "Some string to compare"` (change this) and now compare `jst` with `getString("arrow_val")` using `jst.equals(abcd.getString("arrow_val"))` in your if loop

Comment: it shows null pointer at              if(j.equals(b.get("arrowvisi")))

Comment: can you put your logcat in the question .. that will be helpful

Comment: You don't need to check the if statement i.e ` j.equals(b.get("arrowvisi") ` as it will always be true in your case

Comment: Thanks :D I have edited my ans, so that you understand more. The if statements with `j` and `jst` should be improved. Feel free to ask anything you don't understand ..

Comment: can you help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951608/java-lang-classcastexception-android-view-viewgrouplayoutparams-cannot-be-cast

Answer (score 0):

First of all,to compare strings in java,you need to use `.equals`

so change

```
 if(j==b.get("arrowvisi"))
```

to

```
 if(j.equals(b.getString("arrowvisi")))
```

and

```
if(jst==abcd.get("arrow_val"))
```

to

```
if(jst.equals(abcd.getString("arrow_val")))
```

And second,your condition always will be true,because you are comparing two equal values always,i.e. first getting value in `jst` and then comparing same value.

Edit : to resolve null pointer change

```
 String j =(String) b.get("arrowvisi");
```

to

```
 String j = b.getString("arrowvisi");
```

and

```
 String jst =(String) abcd.get("arrow_val");
```

to

```
 String jst =abcd.getString("arrow_val");
```

And post logcat exception.

Comment: and my if else structure is right? my logic is right?

Comment: @jimmy It depends on your requirement.

Comment: still it shows   same error at this line           if(j.equals(b.get("arrowvisi")))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451589/how-to-set-values-after-using-mdoel-class-for-global-arraylist

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
String j = (String) b.get("arrowvisi");
```

with

```
String j = b.getString("arrowvisi");
```

and

```
String jst = (String) abcd.get("arrow_val");
```

with

```
String jst = abcd.getString("arrow_val");
```

also put this in bracket()

```
b.get("arrowvisi")
abcd.get("arrow_val")
```